# mapM for Data.Set in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I have some Haskell code in which I'd like to work with `Data.Set`.
Basically because I didn't look into alternatives much and need a structure to store elements of Ord without duplicates.

I've now come to a situation where I'd like to have something like mapM for Data.Set
so that I can perform monadic operations on a sets individual elements.
I already searched [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) for a type like `(a -> m b) -> Set a -> m (Set b)` but didn't find anything useful.

I also looked into `Data.Traversable` just to find out that it has instances for [], Maybe and (Map k) but not for Set.

So my questions are:

1. Why is there no mapM for Set in Data.Set?
2. Is there already a package that delivers something like mapM that I missed?
3. Is it discouraged to want to mapM over Sets? (why and what are alternatives?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem is that `Traversable` requires `Functor`, and sets cannot be functors since they require an `Ord` constraint while functors must be unconstrained.

However, sets are foldable so if you don't need to collect the results, you can use `mapM_` from `Data.Foldable`.

If you do need the results, you can go via lists, e.g.

```
fromList <$> mapM f (toList s)
```

Comment: Yeah - I thought about doing it via lists, I just hoped that there was a better solution.

Comment: If your map function is not monotonic (i.e. does not satisfy `x < y` implies `f x < f y`) then going via lists is not significantly worse than the best you could do.  If it is monotonic, then yeah, it's too bad there is no `mapMonotonicM`.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.6) package. It provides a more general abstraction for traversals (among many other things). While it doesn't solve the problem of having an efficient `mapM` for `Set`s, it allows to express traversals for constrained data types:

```
import Control.Lens.Traversal
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

-- forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> Set a -> f (Set b)
setTraversal :: (Ord b) => Traversal (Set a) (Set b) a b
setTraversal f = (fmap Set.fromList) . traverse f . Set.toList

main = do
    print $ mapMOf setTraversal (\x -> [x+1, x-1]) $ Set.fromList [0, 10, 20]
```

Note that the documentation for `Set.toList` says that it's subject to list fusion. With some luck (depending on the applicative in question) the intermediate lists could get fused away.

Comment: Keep is mind that your `setTraversal` isn't a legal `Traversal` (which is why [`Data.Set.Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/latest/doc/html/Data-Set-Lens.html) doesn't export it). In particular, it can change the number of elements in the Set, which can break the `Traversal` laws.

Comment: @shachaf Yes, that's true. If the traversing function isn't [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) on a set then the result will have less elements than the original.